# LiveCD: Running a sh script on startup

Tags: permissions, live-cd, sh, autorun

I have created sh script that backs up computers to a network location, and I'm trying to make a LiveCD of Ubuntu-Mini Remix 14.04 that will be able to launch the script without a GUI.
The script does require some user input so I need to figure out a way for it to be interactive, as well as it needs to run as root.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by launching the script as root from the bash.bashrc file. This file runs in the interactive terminal whenever the terminal is started, and as this was a live CD there is no user login set up so it ran perfectly for my purposes.